# How to migrate or move multiple modules in a given branch from svn to git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I've the following hierarchy in my svn repository -

- branches

  - Branch1

    - folder1

      - module1
      - module2
      - module3
    - folder2

      - module1
      - module2
- tags
- trunk

I need to migrate the Branch1 to git. Is it possible to migrate?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

To only do a partial import of a SVN repository you can use `git svn clone <svn repo url>/branches/Branch1 --no-minimize-url`

For more info see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn